# Choose a lockType in solrconfig.xml for multiple EmbeddedSolrServers

Tags: java, solr

When I upgraded my solr from 3.6.2 to 7.3 in my system, I can't make the index lock work.
Here is my system:

1. Two Tomcat web Java apps access the same solr home by EmbeddedSolrServer instances (under same JVM). One app is read-only and the other writes indexes to the solr home. Both work in a multi-thread environment.
2. Each app uses a single pattern to get only one EmbeddedSolrServer instance. Here is the code to generate the EmbeddedSolrServer instance (I omit the singleton part):

   ```
   coreContainer = new CoreContainer(solrHomeDir);
   coreContainer.load();
   collectionName = getCollectionName();
   solrServer = new EmbeddedSolrServer(coreContainer, collectionName);`
   ```

When solr is 3.6.2, the lockType is `native` and system works perfectly.

However, when solr is 7.3, the lockType of `native` doesn't work. The app (read process) which initializes EmbeddedSolrServer in the latter time always get an excpeiton - java.nio.channels.OverlappingFileLockException when it tries to get the solr core (solr core is not available) . While another app (write process) works good.

According to page https://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/AvailableLockFactories, I also tried those types: `none`, `single` and `simple`. None of them works well.

When I choose `none` and `single`, both app work good when it is a single thread operation. When it handles multiple-thread writing process, it throws an index file NotFoundException.

When I choose `simple`, the read process which initialize latter always get an exception -

> SolrCore 'collection1' is not available due to init failure: Index dir >'/var/solr-home/data/index/' of core 'collection1' is already locked. The most >likely cause is another Solr server (or another solr core in this server) also >configured to use this directory; other possible causes may be specific to >lockType: simple

Tomcat 7
Java 1.8

I really appreciate if you can give any input here.